# How to convert result distance of haversine formula in mysql

Tags: mysql

I got query witch gives me a distance.

```
(6378 * acos(cos(radians(".$lat.")) * cos(radians(p1.lat)) * cos( radians(p1.lng) - radians(".$lng.")) + sin(radians(".$lat.")) *
                sin(radians(p1.lat)))) AS distance
```

Result is for example: 0.0000972987365289 how to get normal human readable in kilometers ?

Answer (score 0):

use the [ST_DISTANCE_SPHER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere)E which gives back meters

```
SELECT

ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE(POINT(".$lng.", ".$lat."), POINT(v, p1.lat)) / 1000 AS distance
```

Comment: ok but is possible to do that in php now, dont wanna do next query to database. I can convert this to meter or need new special query to do that ?

Comment: I dont understan what is this value, can you explain please ?

Comment: you can replace your existing query and get meters, so run it on your database. the newer function are faster that the "old" fashion way. You can take your php and replace it one on one in your code. Ans What should i explain, you can see the definition of the function if you follow the link. Besides you didin'T post any php code anyway.